Transformers Trainer: How do `seed` and `data_seed` differ?
HuggingFace's Trainer() has both a seed and a data_seed. I'm sweeping both and I find that seed makes a difference but data_seed makes literally zero difference (not even a minor numerical difference).
What is the role then of data_seed?
